# Firefox Profile Not working

Tags: firefox, selenium

Below is my non-working code for the Firefox profile.

```
@Before

public void setUp() throws Exception {

  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);

  profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/Location");

  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/docx");

  driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);

  baseUrl = "<URL>";

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test

public void test1() throws Exception {

  driver.get("URL");

  driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("username");

  driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Password");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rowCell0']/td[4]/a[4]")).click();// This line of code is for Download Link on the UI
```

Now once selenium clicks on it, Firefox will again open the confirmation box asking for "Open with" and "Save File".

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error, but every-time i run this code, Firefox will always open the confirmation box when clicked on download link(But,actually have written to not to open it and download it directly when clicked). I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove 
      profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);

and try it should work...let me know

Comment: Hello, I tried doing this now but still the mozilla firefox will open up the confirmation box for open with and Save File. Is there any other method where we can follow to download the word document from the UI given link?

Comment: Add this to your code and try-
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too and it blocked me several days! 
Please make sure the file type you are trying to download, and then configure with the correct value in below line:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/docx");
```

Your site source code is sending back a content header saying the file is xxx to match the preferences you have set.

To reference, the types may be: application/octet-stream, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/plain, application/zip, application/exe, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download

Comment: you can find the MIME types for different file type in the following link

http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/   - See more at: http://qaautomationworld.blogspot.in/2014/02/file-downlaoding-using-selenium.html#sthash.i28o3uHY.dpuf